# SQL creating function got error on the return part

Tags: sql, function, return

Can anyone please let me know where of the SQL query is wrong?

The error is

> Incorrect syntax near "return"

Code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(@N INT) 
RETURNS INT 
AS
BEGIN
    WITH ranksalary AS
    (
        SELECT
            salary, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS Rank
        FROM
            Employee
    )
    RETURN (SELECT Salary AS getNthHighestSalary 
            FROM ranksalary
            WHERE Rank = @N);
END
```

Comment: are you missing a ; after Employee) ?

Comment: Added ":" and it still give me the error....

Comment: semicolon (;) not colon (:)

Comment: This is not SQL. What language is this?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: You can **NOT** return an expression - you need to first store the value from that `SELECT` into a local variable in your function, and then return that variable's value.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like T-SQL to me. As @marc_s already pointed out you need to store the value in a variable first and then return that.

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(@N INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result int
    ;WITH ranksalary AS
    (
        SELECT
            salary, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS [Rank]
        FROM
            Employee
    )
    SELECT @result = Salary
      FROM ranksalary
      WHERE [Rank] = @N

    RETURN @result
END

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use this logic?

```
declare @rank;

select @rank = count(*) + 1
from employee
where salary > @salary;

return @rank;
```